# You are given the sides of a triangle $a,b,c$ Prove that: $a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(c+a-b)+c^2(a+b-c)\le 3abc$ (Sweden 1950)

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, contest-math, problem-solving, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

You are given the sides of a triangle $a,b,c$ Prove that: $a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(c+a-b)+c^2(a+b-c)\le 3abc$

I was just doing the question above and solved it in the following manner:

$a^2b+a^2c-a^3+b^2c+b^2a-b^3+c^2a+c^2b-c^3-3abc\le 0$

$(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)+2b^2c+2ac^2+2a^2b-a^3-b^3-c^3-3abc\le0$

And this is where I got stuck. Could you please explain to me how to finish it off from here? [Prove that $a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(a+c-b)+c^2(a+b-c) \leq 3abc.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597158/prove-that-a2bc-ab2ac-bc2ab-c-leq-3abc) I realise that this question has been asked before, but my main query, is how my train of thought could be used to finish off the question

Comment: Does this duplicate question answer your question? [Prove that $a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(a+c-b)+c^2(a+b-c) \leq 3abc.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597158/prove-that-a2bc-ab2ac-bc2ab-c-leq-3abc)

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question, as what I really want to know is how I could finish off the question, using my thought pattern

Comment: thanks for the suggestion though @Somos

Comment: Your inequality is not right if $a< b< c$...

Comment: But you have not explained your steps. Please do so in the body of the question. Also please acknowledge in the body of the question that the same question was aksed before.

Comment: ok, sure doing it right now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $a\ge b\ge c$ this means $$c(a+b-c)\ge b(a+c-b)\ge a(c+b-a)$$

Now by rearrangement inequality $$\tag{1}a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(c+a-b)+c^2(a+b-c)\le \sum_{cyc} ba(b+c-a)$$

Similarly, $$\tag{2}a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(c+a-b)+c^2(a+b-c)\le \sum_{cyc} ca(b+c-a)$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we complete our proof.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer, could you please explain to me though, how it can also be finished off, using my train of thought

Comment: @Michael  this is a different method , i don't know how to finish using your method.I only saw your edit now

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Friend, this is from a book!

Comment: Say me please, which is it from?

Comment: @BookOfFlames of course   i had read it fromzdravko's inequality book,

Comment: Oh! I just needed to talk to you, I think that you could be a good guide to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113612/discussion-between-book-of-flames-and-albus-dumbledore).

Answer (score 1):

It's a triangle, so let
\begin{eqnarray*}
u&=&b+c-a \\
v&=&c+a-b \\ 
w&=&a+b-c
\end{eqnarray*} and these quantities are non negative.

So your inequality is equivalent to
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 (u(v+w)^2+v(w+u)^2+w(u+v)^2) \leq 3(u+v)(v+w)(w+u)
\end{eqnarray*}
or
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \sum u^2 v +12 uvw \leq 3 \sum u^2 v +6 uvw 
\end{eqnarray*}
which is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Because your way does not give a solution.

We can use SOS here.

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-a^3)\leq3abc$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+ab^2-a^3-b^3)\leq\sum_{cyc}(abc-a^3)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-abc)\leq\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b)$$ or
$$(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)\leq\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b)$$ or
$$(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\leq2\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b-c)\geq0$$ and we are done!