# Prove $a^3+b^3+c^3 + 3abc \ge a^2(b+c)+b^2(a+c)+c^2(a+b)$ for $a,b,c >0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Problem:**
Prove $a^3+b^3+c^3 + 3abc \ge a^2(b+c)+b^2(a+c)+c^2(a+b)$, for $ a,b,c >0$

I've been playing around with this inequality for a while but kept running into dead ends. I've tried AM-GM inequality, tried to establish bounds, ect...
The one fact that I found probably useful is that: $(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)=a^3+b^3+c^3 + a^2(b+c)+b^2(a+c)+c^2(a+b)$. But still couldn't make good use of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You are given the sides of a triangle $a,b,c$ Prove that: $a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(c+a-b)+c^2(a+b-c)\le 3abc$ (Sweden 1950)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3847525/you-are-given-the-sides-of-a-triangle-a-b-c-prove-that-a2bc-ab2ca-b) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E3%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E3%2B3abc%5Cge%20a%5E2(b%2Bc)%2Bb%5E2(a%2Bc)%2Bc%5E2(a%2Bb)%24&p=1).

Comment: FYI, there's also the one closed as a duplicate of the one above, i.e., [Prove that $a^2(b+c-a)+b^2(a+c-b)+c^2(a+b-c) \leq 3abc.$](/q/1597158), plus [Prove inequality in a triangle](/q/835074), where its [answer](/a/835095) explicitly states your inequality is just a rewritten version. In addition, there's the related AoPS threads [Hard or Trivial?](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1562427p9558168), [can you solve this problem?](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1564877p9583474) and [Plis enlighten me](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1454446p8362399).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use Schur's inequality for the case $r = 1$. You essentially prove Schur's inequality special case. You might look up Wikipedia about this particular powerful inequality. I highly doubt it that you can prove it using AM-GM or CS inequality.